# Water has been turned off for over a year

Tags: water, new-home

I'm looking at a house today that has had the water shut off for 2 years. Should I be concerned about this? What kind of damages could it have caused overtime, if any?

Thank you!

Comment: How old is the house?  What types of pipes?  Was any "winterization" done or was it just turned off and left?

Comment: I'm assuming that it was just turn off and left. Built in 1947. Not sure about the pipes because it was not listed in the description.

Comment: at the least require the seller to have the water on before your inspection. (including pressurizing heating systems).

Comment: I’d the place has been empty that long, watch out... lots of metal things.. pipe, wire, ductwork, as well as furnaces, air conditioning compressors etc all tend to grow legs and walk away.

Comment: Not to mention other things that might grow inside of them.